# How to handle null pointer exception in human task's

Tags: events, error-handling, rollback, bpmn, kogito

I have tried using error boundary events in the human task but its not taking the boundary path just throwing java error can someone help me with that?

[workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqrVS.png)

i tried to send the process to boundary event path but it throws java error in console

Answer (score 0):

See https://blog.kie.org/2021/07/error-handling-in-kogito.html, this might help to fix your issue